# How do I receive data from NTP server?

Tags: c++, ntp

I have no idea why send data is 48 bytes 010,0,0..., someone can explain? the problem is buffer for data received, I don't know how big he should be, and even if I receive data, how to make normal time from it?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#define WIN32_MEAN_AND_LEAN

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include <time.h>



using namespace std;

class HRException
{
public:
    HRException() :
        m_pMessage("") {}
    virtual ~HRException() {}
    HRException(const char *pMessage) :
        m_pMessage(pMessage) {}
    const char * what() { return m_pMessage; }
private:
    const char *m_pMessage;
};

const int  REQ_WINSOCK_VER = 2; // Minimum winsock version required
const char DEF_SERVER_NAME[] = "0.pl.pool.ntp.org";
const int  SERVER_PORT = 123;
const int  TEMP_BUFFER_SIZE = 128;

const char msg[48] = { 010,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };


// IP number typedef for IPv4
typedef unsigned long IPNumber;

IPNumber FindHostIP(const char *pServerName)
{
    HOSTENT *pHostent;

    // Get hostent structure for hostname:
    if (!(pHostent = gethostbyname(pServerName)))
        throw HRException("could not resolve hostname.");

    // Extract primary IP address from hostent structure:
    if (pHostent->h_addr_list && pHostent->h_addr_list[0])
        return *reinterpret_cast<IPNumber*>(pHostent->h_addr_list[0]);

    return 0;
}

void FillSockAddr(sockaddr_in *pSockAddr, const char *pServerName, int portNumber)
{
    // Set family, port and find IP
    pSockAddr->sin_family = AF_INET;
    pSockAddr->sin_port = htons(portNumber);
    pSockAddr->sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = FindHostIP(pServerName);
}

bool RequestHeaders(const char *pServername)
{
    SOCKET      hSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    char        tempBuffer[TEMP_BUFFER_SIZE];
    sockaddr_in sockAddr = { 0 };
    bool        bSuccess = true;

    try
    {
        // Lookup hostname and fill sockaddr_in structure:
        cout << "Looking up hostname " << pServername << "... ";
        FillSockAddr(&sockAddr, pServername, SERVER_PORT);
        cout << "found.\n";

        // Create socket
        cout << "Creating socket... ";
        if ((hSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
            throw HRException("could not create socket.");
        cout << "created.\n";

        // Connect to server
        cout << "Attempting to connect to " << inet_ntoa(sockAddr.sin_addr)
            << ":" << SERVER_PORT << "... ";
        if (connect(hSocket, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&sockAddr), sizeof(sockAddr)) != 0)
            throw HRException("could not connect.");
        cout << "connected.\n";

        cout << "Sending request... ";

        // send request part 1
        if (send(hSocket, msg, sizeof(msg) , 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            throw HRException("failed to send data.");



        cout << "request sent.\n";

        cout << "Dumping received data...\n\n";
        // Loop to print all data

        recv(hSocket, tempBuffer, sizeof(tempBuffer), 0);  // <-- the problem
    ///
       //part where we take time out of tempBuffer

    ///







    }
    catch (HRException e)
    {
        cerr << "\nError: " << e.what() << endl;
        bSuccess = false;
    }

    if (hSocket != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        closesocket(hSocket);
    }
    return bSuccess;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int iRet = 1;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    cout << "Initializing winsock... ";

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(REQ_WINSOCK_VER, 0), &wsaData) == 0)
    {
        // Check if major version is at least REQ_WINSOCK_VER
        if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) >= REQ_WINSOCK_VER)
        {
            cout << "initialized.\n";

            // Set default hostname:
            const char *pHostname = DEF_SERVER_NAME;

            // Set custom hostname if given on the commandline:
            if (argc > 1)
                pHostname = argv[1];

            iRet = !RequestHeaders(pHostname);
        }
        else
        {
            cerr << "required version not supported!";
        }

        cout << "Cleaning up winsock... ";

        // Cleanup winsock
        if (WSACleanup() != 0)
        {
            cerr << "cleanup failed!\n";
            iRet = 1;
        }
        cout << "done.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "startup failed!\n";
    }
    int x;
    cin >> x;

    return iRet;
}
```

Most part of code is from madwizard.org

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking generally how to deal with the winsocks library? Or is this about NTP? I went to madwizard.com and I couldn't find **any** code there. Are you sure that is the source of this source code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time from NTP server in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511951/time-from-ntp-server-in-c).

Comment: Sorry, it is madwizard.org not madwizard.com, my question is more about NTP(but im total noob in winsock also), i want to know why request for time to NTP server is 48bytes char array, and when  it comes to getting data from NTP server how big should be buffer?

Answer (score 1):

Ok it works, main part of code:

```
        const char msg[48] = { 010,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };

        if (send(hSocket, msg, sizeof(msg) , 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            throw HRException("failed to send data.");



        cout << "request sent.\n";

        cout << "Dumping received data...\n\n";


        char   tempBuffer[1024];
        int bytes =  recv(hSocket, tempBuffer, sizeof(tempBuffer), 0);  
        cout << "bytes received: " << bytes << endl;

        time_t tmit;
        tmit = ntohl(((time_t*)tempBuffer)[4]);
        tmit -= 2208988800U;

        cout << ctime(&tmit);
```

No idea why data that we send is

```
msg[48] = { 010,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
```

and why received data contains many numbers? for example if change code to

`tmit = ntohl(((time_t*)tempBuffer)[6]);`

I will get date 2008y, why?

Guys why so many minuses?, still waiting for an explanation :D

Here's whole code http://pastebin.com/Sv3ERGfV , dont forget to link ws2_32.lib

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [my issue](https://github.com/ethanlim/NetworkTimeProtocol/issues/1) when trying to query the time from a [self-hostet Windows-NTP-Server](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/22144502/how-do-you-configure-your-pc-as-ntp-server-?dti=0&lc=en-WW) with the C++ library [NTPClient](https://github.com/ethanlim/NetworkTimeProtocol) which uses boost for the network tasks, `msg[48] = { 010,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };` configures the *ntp.flags.mode*. After comparing the network traffic of `w32tm /stripchart /computer:10.159.96.65` using Wireshark, flag 27 or 11 seem to be the choices for my usecase:
[Comparison of NTP network packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GarBD.png)

`tmit = ntohl(((time_t*)tempBuffer)[6]);` extracts the data from the received package. It looks like

- 4 yields the reference time (last sync with timeserver I assume),
- 8 the time when server received request and
- 10 the transmit time (which should be almost equal).