# how to get ntp information to program level

Tags: c++, ntp

I have some machines (`linux`) on `ntp setup`. they are running some apps (`c++` written) that talk to each other. I need the app A of machine A to get ntp information from machine B through app B. What is the best way to do so?

I mean some ntp information like if/in case the clocks are out of sync

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "NTP information"?

Comment: Anything wrong with a tcp socket and just transferring the data?

Comment: Sorry i mean some ntp information like if/in case the clocks are out of sync.

Comment: dutt, can I get the ntp clock/outOfSync information through tcp socket?

Comment: I would suggest simply using an NTP library or external NTP program on each machine. Trying to push NTP information through the link is only going to complicate things unless you have a good reason to do so?

Comment: @Jon-Cage tanx. Is there any good ntp library out there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326677/is-there-any-c-c-library-to-connect-with-a-remote-ntp-server

Comment: @Jon-Cage tanx. i did not really understand it. is the libntp installed if i install ntp? or how do i get it.

Comment: i think ntp_gettime() also looks good http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ntp_gettime

Comment: Just set the machines to synchronize...

Answer (score -1):

I used ntp_gettime() from sys/timex.h.

REF: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man2/ntp_gettime.2.html