# How to check the real date through an internet connection

Tags: c++, windows, date

I have problem about getting online date from time.windows.com with C++.
I just wanna get label from C++ with online time.

I got references but i dont know how to convert into C++ code.
http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/c-get-nist-internet-time/
and
http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[rdate](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc868.txt) is a simple network protocol but you may find few servers providing this.

An alternative that is practical is to use the Date header from an HTTP server [See section 14.18](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). Here is a write up for [httpdate](http://daniel-lange.com/archives/37-httpdate-set-local-date-and-time-from-a-web-server.html) which uses this approach.

Finally, [SNTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4330) is not really that difficult to use. It is *far* simpler than full-blown NTP.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might not be as simple as you imagined.
There are basically three approaches you can take:

1. Get the date/time from some [NTP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).
   This approach basically means connecting to the server via Sockets (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326677/is-there-any-c-c-library-to-connect-with-a-remote-ntp-server) and [this](http://www.abnormal.com/~thogard/ntp/ntpdate.c)), or using an existing C++ library like [net-snmp](http://www.net-snmp.org/), [snmp++](http://www.agentpp.com/snmp_pp3_x/snmp_pp3_x.html) or [this SNTP implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/csntp.aspx?df=100&forumid=561&exp=0&select=5205)
2. Get the HTML page that displays this value and parse it for your value. It is best to use an existing HTML parser for this, like [TinyXPath](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxpath/). I wouldn't go this way because it is unnecessarily complicated.
3. Using a web service like like [earthtools](http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm). You'll pass the necessary arguments in the URL and you receive the XML response which you can then parse.

I realize none of these solutions are as easy as you would want them to be, but when restricted to C++ they are all I can think of at this time.

Comment: hmm im newbie here in C++ programming, i can not get it all sry....my C++ can not detect #include <sys/socket.h> for socket things,how i can try this?

Comment: Windows socket programming is different than Linux. Search online for resources about c++ socket programming for Windows, there are plenty. However, I would suggest going with one of the libraries if you are a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps someone out there, I have a personal method which really works for my date and time checking purposes(using C++ ), with NO need for too much accuracy (It is used to keeping track of roughly how many days an non-paying client has used my software for etc)

I have web server with a single-line PHP script (echo date("d-m-Y")), which I call using WinHTTP from my C++ code; parse the resulting string, and voila!